# Powershell: Run by looking at servers in server.txt file

Tags: powershell

I want my code to run by looking at servers in a server.txt file rather than inputting the servername in the rootpath each time as i want to run on 20+ servers:

the code is below:

```
$ServerList = Get-Content "servers.txt"
        $OutFile = "C:\Users\munjanga\Documents\AoN Project\Execute\$([Environment]::MachineName).txt"  
    $Header = "Account,Ace String,Object Path"
    Del $OutFile
    Add-Content -Value $Header -Path $OutFile 

ForEach($Server in $ServerList) {

    $RootPath = "C:\Users\munjanga\Documents\Operations Orchestration"
$Folders = dir $RootPath -recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true}
$isInherited = @{
 $true  = 'Inherited'
 $false = 'Not Inherited'
}

$inheritance = @{
 0 = 'files only'
 1 = 'this folder and subfolders'
 2 = 'this folder and files'
  3 = 'subfolders and files'
}

$fldr = $Folder.FullName

$Folders | % {
$fldr = $_.FullName
Get-Acl $fldr | select -Expand Access |
 select @{n='Account';e={$_.IdentityReference}},
     @{n='Ace String';e={"{0} {1}, {2} ({3})" -f $_.AccessControlType,
       $_.FileSystemRights, $inheritance[$_.InheritanceFlags],
       $isInherited[$_.IsInherited]}},
    @{n='Object Path';e={$fldr}} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select -Skip 1 | % {$_ -replace '"', ""} | Out-File $OutFile -Force -Encoding ascii -Append}
```

Comment: -1 for unclear problem statement and code dump. Please read the [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and especially on section *Help others reproduce the problem*.

Comment: You have asked several questions in a very short period of time, all around this same script/task. I suggest you stop, take a step back & learn more PowerShell fundamentals before throwing a bunch of code at SO & then asking people to debug it all for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the whole thing in `Get-Content | ForEach-Object` like this:

```
Get-Content servers.txt | ForEach-Object {
   $RootPath = $_
   #Your code
   }
```

Comment: I will read on those thank you, so i have amended it as you have said to something in the script above i have amended it as above.